# Passing a function with single or multiple arguments into another function

Tags: python, algorithm, function, recursion, time

I am doing some algorithm running time analysis on some simple factorial algorithms, and to avoid code repetition I am trying to create a single time analysis function that will take the different factorial algorithm functions as arguements.

When I pass in factorial functions (e.g. iterative) that only take one argument this works fine, but as part of my assignment I have to use a tail recursive algorithm also, which takes 2 arguments (n,accumlator). Here is my code:

```py
def iterFactorial(n):
    
    #running product
    factorial = 1
    
    #multiply each number in range 1 to n by the running product(i.e. the factorial)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        
        factorial *= i
    #return the factorial
    return factorial 


def tail_Recur_Factorial(n,accumulator):
    
    if n == 1:
        return accumulator
    return tail_Recur_Factorial(n-1,n*accumulator)

running_times_1 = []
n_values = [i for i  in range(1,1000,100)]

def TimeAnalyis(function):
    
    #array for storing  multiple temporary running times of algorithm for a given n
    temp_time = [0]

    
    for n in n_values:
        
    
        #run fucntion 50 times for each given n value 
        for i in range(50):
            
            #take current timestamp
            start_time = time.time()
            
            #run function
            function(n)
            
            #take current timestamp
            end_time = time.time()
            
            #calculate time taken for function to run
            function_time = end_time - start_time
            
            #append to temp time array so mean can be taken
            temp_time.append(function_time)
            
        #take average running time
        running_times_1.append(statistics.mean(temp_time))
        
        #reset temp time
        temp_time = [0]
```

The time analysis fucntion works fine for the iterative factorial function, where I call like:

timeAnalysis(iterFactorial)

How can I modify the time analysis function to allow me to *ALSO* pass in the tail recrusive fucntion which takes two arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code:

**You can create a decorator for this.**

```py
def TimeAnalyis(func):
    #Takes any number of args and kwargs
    def wrapper(*args,**kargs):
        best = float('inf')
        for i in range(50):
            start = time.time()
            # Calls function and stores returned values in result
            result = func(*args,**kargs)
            total = time.time()-start
            if total<best:
                best = total
        # Print best timing
        print(f'Best time taken is {best} seconds')
        # returns the values returned by function
        return result
    # returns wrapper function
    return wrapper

#decorator
@TimeAnalyis
def anyfunc(n,m):
    for i in range(n):
         print(i*m)
```

Comment: That has solved the issue.